# Display a random string from an array on the click of a button [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a simple app that displays a random question. I can successfully display a random string from an array on mount and page refresh.

I would like to display a different random question 'onClick' of a button rather than refresh the page?

Heres the code so far:

```js
export const QuestionContainer = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(res => setResponse(res));
  }, []);

  const { records = [] } = response;

  const questions = records.map(record => record.fields.question);

  console.table(questions);

 // const randomNum = arr => {
 //   return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
 //  };

  return (
    <div className='questions-container'>
      <h1>{questions[0]}?</h1>
      <button onClick={() => console.log('more')}>More</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `const questions` is an array of strings example - ['hello', 'world', 'noob question']

Comment: add another `useState`, f.e. `index`, on click `setIndex(randomValue)`, render questions[index] ...  nobody read docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! Just use the onClick to set the index that's being displayed, and you're golden! This should work:

```
const randomIndex = (arr) => { // returns a random int value to use as an index
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
}
export const QuestionContainer = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0) // 0 initially, as you had in your example

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(res => setResponse(res));
  }, []);

  const { records = [] } = response;

  const questions = records.map(record => record.fields.question);

  console.table(questions);

  return (
    <div className='questions-container'>
      <h1>{questions[index]}?</h1>
      <button onClick={_ => setIndex(randomIndex(questions)}>More</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use another API Random Quote with a button:

```
 
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const randomIndex = (arr) => { // returns a random int value to use as an index
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  }

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const quoteAPI = async () => {
    let arrayOfQuotes = [];

try {
      const data = await axios.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skolakoda/programming-quotes-api/master/backup/quotes.json");
      arrayOfQuotes = data.data;
      console.log(arrayOfQuotes);
      const quote = arrayOfQuotes.map((arrayOfQuote) =>
        <div key={arrayOfQuote.id}>
          <h3>{arrayOfQuote.en}</h3>
          <p>{arrayOfQuote.author}</p>

        </div>);
      console.log(quote);
      setQuote(quote);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    quoteAPI();
  }, []);

  return (<div className="App">
    <h4>{quote[index]}</h4>
    <button onClick={_ => setIndex(randomIndex(quote))}>Get Random Quote</button>
  </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```